# G+ in Android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, google-plus-one

I created an activity in my app that contains a webview in that I put a google plus button following this tutorial [Android +1 button in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813106/android-1-button-in-webview) . But I have a big problem! The button works great, but it appears very very little! How can I handle this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the webviews zoom settings.

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```