# Unable to +1 using google Plus or google auth api

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am unable to +1 using google Plus or google auth api.  This function works fine on every other device except my galaxy 10.1 note.  Even when going through Google Plus i get the error message "Can't +1 the post".
Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had this issue and after trying for quite a long time, I found out that you cannot do it through the API directly. Here is a short description of what I did to work around it:

- This only works for a Google Plus Page - get the snippet that you would normally see on a webpage. That includes some html+javascript+ajax and save it as a string variable in your android code.
- Then secondly, load it in a webview - that will load the Plus 1 Button for a user to click (that means they follow or recommend it depending on which button you have).
- Once they have clicked it, you can make another API call to verify that they actually clicked it - you see, there is no easy way to know this because you have no control over the html button.
- I figured that when they authorize the app, request permission to read their circle count and then if they actually clicked the plus one button, compare the final count with the original count to make sure they did indeed follow/+1 your page.

If you don't use this approach, please let me know how you pull it off.

Check out this answer on how to load the button in a web view:

[Load Plus One Button In WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813106/android-1-button-in-webview)

Good luck.